# Having an issue with jQuery, AJAX and PHP (posting)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I am using JQuery and AJAX to post to a PHP file which will eventually parse the data and insert it in a database.

I'm having issue display trying to see what's wrong with my javascript that it will not post the PHP file.

I know it is not posting because I don't recieve and email which is the first function in the PHP file.

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ptitle = $("#name").val();
    var pdesc = $("#desc").val();
    var pemail = $("#email.").val();
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        sendValue(ptitle, pdesc, pemail);
    });
});

function sendValue(ptitle, pdesc, pemail) {
    $.post("<?=MOLLY.'update.php'?>", {
        stitle: ptitle,
        sdesc: pdesc,
        semail: pemail
    }, function(data) {
        //
    }, "json");
}
```

PHP

```
mail($myemail,'test','test');

if ($_POST){
$title = $_POST['stitle'];
$email = $_POST['semail'];  
mail($myemail,$email,$title);

}
```

Comment: 1) Are you sure that `"<?=MOLLY.'update.php'?>"` is giving you the correct URL? - Check the HTML source the PHP renders. Check whether you need a leading `/` or not. 2) Is `#submit` a submit button in a form or a hyperlink? If it is, you'll need to cancel the default event occuring (accept the event object as the first parameter, and then call event.preventDefault()).

Comment: Use firebug in Firefox to check the AJAX request - that would be first place to check.

Comment: Instead of "if ($_POST)" you should use "if(isset($_POST['stitle']))".

Comment: Is that short tags "<?=" is working?

Comment: molly is the right url and the submit is a <span> thanks though

Comment: As mentioned, use Firebug to see if you are getting anything posted or errors.  Do you need quotes around the variable names, "stitle" : ptitle, "sdesc" : pdesc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ptitle = $("#name").val();
    var pdesc = $("#desc").val();
    var pemail = $("#email.").val();  // <---- I assume you meant "#email".
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        sendValue(ptitle, pdesc, pemail);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by checking that your PHP file runs, replace the content with something like:

PHP

```
echo "Im running";
```

Then in your JS do:

```
$.post("<?=MOLLY.'update.php'?>", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}, "json");
```

and see if the message is returned and logged in the console.
If it is, check your $_POST by echoing back the values you sent, also echo back your email variable to see that it outputs correctly.

If it all works fine, you need to check if your server is set up correctly for the mail command to actually be able to send an email, as the problem is most likely serverside when everything else is eliminated.

Oh, and you should do what cillosis says, use isset and check something in the $_POST superglobal, not just a `if($_POST)`, but since your running the mail function before that in your PHP, that's probably not your main problem.